# Get size of file on remote server

Tags: sftp

I have a requirement where I need to do SFTP connection to remote server, get the size of the file on remote server and depending on the size, i need to get the file onto local server.
Is there any command in SFTP to get the size of the file.

Comment: What SFTP? SFTP is protocol. What SFTP client are you using? What platform are you on?

Answer (score 12):

If you'd like the size output to be human readable, try: `ls -lah`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file size of the remote files using the `ls` command by passing parameters.

To get Size of the file pass `ls -l`

To get Size of the file (HIdden files included) `ls -al`

To get it in human readable format pass `ls -lh` or `ls -alh`

Comment: how can i capture the file size in a variable

Comment: It depends on in which client.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the size using James's with awk

```
ls -l | grep "filename" | awk '{print $5}'
```

If you are using it in a script and want to check using logic, you can store the file size in a variable like so.

```
varname=$(ls -l | grep "filename" | awk '{print $5}')
```

Then call sftp and the task

For a remote file maybe do this

```
filesize=$(ssh user@domain.ex << EOT ls -l | grep "filename" | awk '{print $5}' EOT)
```